# Splitting an image into multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to split an image into many divs . My main aim is to make these divs clickable and replace the clicked div with another image (say the color changes to green for "OK" or red for "error") .How do I make the div clickable ?

Comment: Would you provide a [mcve] to show readers what you are working on? It is a bit hard to advise otherwise.

Comment: https://itekblog.com/css-magic-split-background-image-into-multiple-divs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that safest option would be to split the image first and create separated blocks (divs or tds).

Then you may just change source of the image.

But if you really want to keep one single image, you may consider JavaScript and create event listener for whole image block, while it will check Y, X coordinates of your click and in there it will insert new div on top of it, where you will place the image with some properties (for example background-position, which defines to show just part of this image)...

I guess, that PHP also have some image slicing capabilities, so it may generate "smaller" images for you and based on position (again from JavaScript), you will get source of desired subimage.

### Edit

Also... you can just have that background-image for container div and in that you will place divs with specified width and height, so that they will cover your background, but set visibility to hidden, apply event listeners for all of them, which will just toggle visibility (or just toggle class with visibility).

Comment: This is helpful stuff. However, just as a minor note, we ask that posts here (both questions and answers) are written in a technical style. We'd rather not have voting or meta commentary appearing in posts - that can go in the comments if it is needed.

Comment: Additionally, I wonder if you have misunderstood what a "help vampire" is. Broadly, the definition is a person who asks broad and unresearched questions persistently in a community, and soaks up as much help as they can get before they get ejected or the community fractures from exhaustion. The voting mechanisms are a defence against that, and while they are not perfect, they are the best thing we have at present.

Comment: Oh, I see, that the definition is rather opposite to what I wanted to say. I just saw that word and thought of it as of someone, who seems to be helpful at first, but his only goal is to argue, which is not very productive and it rather drains the person, who needs help, while the arguer is usually getting ego boost.

Comment: Yes, that is different. I imagine it is possible that such a person exists, but I do not like to give false hope to authors who really do write vague, broad or imcomplete questions. We get low-quality material here at a rate of hundreds per day, and I don't want to give those authors the idea that a poor reception was just down to mean people who don't want to help. The problem will still be the question, and reinforcing that message can be helpful.